# Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) is incompatible with nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

Hi I am getting a following error any idea how can i solve this

> Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) is incompatible with nvarchar(max)
>   encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC',
>   encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
>   column_encryption_key_name = 'TEST',
>   column_encryption_key_database_name = 'dev')

Comment: You should at least have added the query that generated this error to the question. Also, more context would have been helpful.